# Inserting values into database that depends on other inputs in a PHP form

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables say Companies and Employees. The table company has three columns, that are ID, Name, Emp_set_id and the table Employees has Emp_id, Company and several other columns.
The Emp_set_id column in Companies table has a value format for each company. Something like below.

```
**ID**  | **Name**  | **Emp_set_id**

01       |  ABC     |   ABCxxxxyy

02       | QWE      |   QWExxxxyy
```

Details:

First three characters in Emp_set_id is the company name.

The next four characters xxxx must be replaced with current year.

The next two characterss yy must be replaced with two digits and it is the number of that employee joining that company and it should auto increment.

When a user fills the form, the details are stored in the Employees table. This part has been done, except for one column, that is Emp_id. Now, while filling the form, if the user selects company as ABC in dropdown box at the form, the value entered in Emp_id should be like ABC202001, ABC202002,... if the company selected is ABC and QWE202001, QWE202002,... if the company selected is QWE. The table should look something like below.

```
**Emp_id** | **Company** | **Emp_name**

ABC202001 | ABC |  John

QWE202001 | QWE | Doe

ABC202002 | ABC | Jane

ABC202003 | ABC | Paul

QWE202002 | QWE | Laura
```

The part where entering the value into Emp_id in the desired format is where I need help.

I have created multiple PHP files for this project. The HTML code segment to display the form is in Employee_tpl.php file. The php code to execute SQL queries for fetching data for the dropdown boxes and inserting values into the table are stored in Employee.php file.

I'm new for both PHP and stack overflow. So, if my question is not clear enough, please imply the content that needs to be elaborated. I have not attached the code here as you may get the idea of my requirement through my words and also due to me not sure of which part of the code to attach.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to get the count from the Employees table added for a compagny this year.

A SQL query will do it :
`SELECT COUNT(Emp_set_id) FROM Employees WHERE Emp_set_id LIKE "QWE2020%";`

Php sample (not tested) :

```
$dbh = new PDO("_________");
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT COUNT(Emp_set_id) as countEmployees FROM Employees WHERE Emp_set_id LIKE :clause;');
$sth->execute([':clause' => $compagnyChar . date('Y').'%']);
$countEmployees = $sth->fetchColumn();
$employeeId = $compagnyChar . date('Y') . str_pad($countEmployees +1, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot kind sir. Though I was not able to use your solution at first as I couldn't completely understand it, I was able to complete it now only with the help of it.